# Extra space at the bottom of CSS columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns, column-count

I have a container that has images inside. I use CSS columns and media queries to determine my layout. I put a paragraph tag at the bottom and noticed extra space at the bottom of it. Here's what i'm talking about in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sEe7x/11/. The weirdness is happening at the yellow and orange break points. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Here's my code

```
-- HTML --

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Portraits</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<body class="photography">
    <nav class="site_navigation cf">
    <ul id="nav_drop" class="nav_links cf">
        <li class="nav_home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav_photography"><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        <li class="nav_projects"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav_contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
        <div class="main photography_wrapper">        



            <h1>Portraits</h2>

            <div class="gallery_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a>                
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
            </div>

            <p>Random collection of portraits.</p>



            <div class="more_galleries">
                <h2>More Galleries</h2>
                <div class="more_gallery_photos">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placedog.com/400/400" alt=""></a>                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.danielcgold.com/js/selectnav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.danielcgold.com/js/functions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>​


-- CSS --

* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cf:before,.cf:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: #fffff6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    padding-top: 6.375em;
    color: #252525;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

strong {
    font-family: 'pt_sans_captionbold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

a {
    color: #ff830a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.selectnav {
    display: none;
}

.site_navigation {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    border-bottom: 0.063em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.375em;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 0.4em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 0.4em;
    -o-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 0.4em;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 0 0.4em;
}

.site_navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    margin: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

.nav_links li {
    float: left;
}

.gallery_wrapper {
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -o-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
    line-height: 0;
}

.more_galleries {
    margin-top: 6em;
}

.more_gallery_photos {
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -o-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}

.more_gallery_photos a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.gallery_wrapper a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.gallery_wrapper img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 60em) {

    .gallery_wrapper {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -o-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -o-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }

    .gallery_wrapper a {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos a {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {

    .nav_links {
        float: left;
    }

    .gallery_wrapper {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -o-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -o-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    .gallery_wrapper a {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos a {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    .site_navigation {
        height: 3.5em;
    }

    .nav_links {
        display: none;
    }

    .selectnav {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 1.5em;
    }

    .gallery_wrapper {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -o-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -o-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .more_gallery_photos a {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
}​
​
```

EDIT: The first fiddle was solved. I updated a JS fiddle with my real code stripped down and recreated the issue. I use SASS so the CSS is the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### It is because of image `<img />` tag rendered as `inline-block`.

```
img {display: block;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUGfe/

Comment: hmm, I do see it working in the fiddle but it's nothing working on my real example page, which unfortunately, is dev at the moment. I know it's a shot in the dark but is there anything else to try? Here's an updated fiddle with more of my default styles added and applied http://jsfiddle.net/sEe7x/5/

Comment: Did you use a CSS Reset? In the above fiddle, you have given this: `img { max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; }` Is this intentional? There is a bottom margin.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, I updated my fiddle in the post and updated the code that i'm using. You can see the error when the pictures span 5 rows.

Comment: @Dan Fiddle not displaying well... Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Try again, I updated the fiddle. I had the image hot linked from my localhost. I also figured out that square images cause the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `display: block` to your images will fix this.

```
img { display: block; }
```

**update:**
Here is an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sEe7x/2/

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

Add his to the column-count block:

```
:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }
```