# Div containing columns is too tall

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

(I've looked at some other questions like this on stack, particularly [Extra space at the bottom of CSS columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851773/extra-space-at-the-bottom-of-css-columns), but I couldn't see the issue the asker was having in the fiddle he presented, and trying that solution didn't work anyways.)

Anyways, I have extra space added below my columns in a div with column-width applied. [Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/EAqE9/) to the an example. My issue is the extra blue space below any columns. When I remove one or another, it seems to settle. Can I have the container div shrink to only use as much space as is needed?

HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="font-console column_div">
        <b>authors:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>author_name</li>
            <li>author_id</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="font-console column_div">
        <b>authors:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>author_name</li>
            <li>author_id</li>
            <li>checked_out</li>
            <li>checked_out</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="font-console column_div">
        <b>checkouts:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>checked_out</li>
            <li>checked_in</li>
            <li>checked_out</li>
            <li>checked_in</li>
            <li>checked_out</li>
            <li>checked_in</li>
            <li>checked_out</li>
            <li>checked_in</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="font-console column_div">
        <b>authors:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>author_name</li>
            <li>author_id</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="font-console column_div">
        <b>books:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>ttttttytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytytyty</li>
            <li>author_id</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #0099ff;
}    

.column_div {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the blue space, it's because of the `UL`.

Just put `margin:0` for the UL tag

```
.columns ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/EAqE9/1/**

Comment: WAT? Why on earth ... alright, thanks. Doing so collapses the vertical spacing between the divs, and adding a margin above or below the blocks makes them not line up properly at the top; any hints?

Comment: add some padding to the .column_div

Answer (score 0):

```
.columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #0099ff;
}

.column_div {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.column_div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.columns ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

One fix to solve the vertical spacing and lack of margin between columns